# Calling R functions from VC++

Tags: c++, r, visual-c++

I need to run statistical functions from R within my C++ code. Is there a way to call them from my C++ code? I'm using VS 2005, do I need to include any header files or link any libraries? I installed R using the standard Windows installer provided from their website.

Regards,

Comment: I found this which looks promising http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html EDIT : This is calling C++ from R, bum :( EDIT : Wait! I have found something http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html :) :)

Comment: Thanks Carl, I already looked into Rcpp and RInside, but they are not giving enough details to work with VS. I was hoping there's someone out there who used R with VS and can tell me what to do.

Comment: Maybe this could shed some light http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=r%20%2Bc%2B%2B&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGAQtwIwCA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DUZkaZhsOfT4&ei=403zTtmxIabh4QTOr7mSCA&usg=AFQjCNGcDNvkB9SwhMsMRj20BvcTYsutCQ

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find much there :(

Comment: a discussion here about R and C# http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Calling-R-functions-into-C-or-C-td904267.html mite be worth a shot :)

Comment: Thanks again. I checked and it turns out that R does not work with Visual Studio, so I need to find myself another statistics library. Would you recommend anything? Boost doesn't have the functions I need.

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746364/best-library-for-statistics-in-c

Answer (score 4):

Briefly:

- As has been stated fairly frequently, R itself does not build under
   VS* making the linking of C code hard-but-possible and C++ code
   impossible (as function header information is not standardized).
- Both Rcpp and RInside work perfectly well on Windows, given the standard
   Windows toolchain.  (RInside did have a bug but this is now fixed.)

  The Rcpp FAQ has more to say about VS* (ie that you cannot expect this
   to work if R itself can't work with the compiler)
- If you *must* use VS* then your best bet may be looser coupling
   via networking and using Rserve.

  If you can switch compilers then Rcpp / RInside can be of interest; and the
   rest of the R API is also at your disposal.
- Rcpp et al have copious documentation, including an Rcpp-introduction pdf (which is 
   also peer-reviewed article) and the aforementioned Rcpp-FAQ --- as well as a dedicated mailing list.

And please do not cross-post. I also just answered this [on r-help](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/250140).

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I just got the reply on r-help as well. I guess I'll have to use something other than R then.

Comment: ...or something other than Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

The binary version of Rserve as provided on https://rforge.net/Rserve/files/ does not build under Microsoft Visual C++. In the file ReadMe.txt, the author indicates that there is no configure for Windows, but there is a special Makefile.win. We did not success to build it, by using "make -f Makefile.win", since no file config.h is provided (only config.h.in).

1. So, comment the following line in the header file Rsrv.h:

   ---

   // # include " config .h"

   ---

At this stage, the following error is generated :

---

rsrv .h (384): fatal error C1189 : # error : " Cannot determine endianness. Make sure config .h is included or _ _{BIG| LITTLE } _ENDIAN__ is defined ."

---

2. Solve the problems related to endianness. In the header file Rsvr.h, replace :

---

```
/* Windows is little-endian is most cases, anywhere else we're stuck*/
 # error "Cannot determine endianness. Make sure config.h is included or  __{BIG|LITTLE}_ENDIAN__ is defined ."
# endif
```

---

by:

---

```
/********* MODIFICATION *************/

/* # error "Cannot determine endianness. Make sure config.h is included or __{BIG|LITTLE}_ENDIAN__ is defined ." */
/************************************/
#define _BIG_ENDIAN (*(uint16_t *)?\xff? < 0x100)
```

---

3. Ensure that the build environment links to the Winsock Library file Ws2_32.lib. To do this, add the following code lines before the main function :

---

```
/* indicate to the linker that the Ws2_32.lib file is needed */
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

---

Applications that use Winsock must be linked with the  Ws2_32.lib library file.

For more details about R and Microsoft Visual C++ integration via Rserve, visit https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305789407_Rserve_for_Windows_case_of_R_and_Microsoft_Visual_C_integration

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.