# Compute probability over a multivariate normal

Tags: java, python, numpy, probability, normal-distribution

My question addresses both mathematical and CS issues, but since I need a performant implementation I am posting it here.

**Problem:**

I have an estimated normal bivariate distribution, defined as a python matrix, but then I will need to transpose the same computation in Java. (dummy values here)

```
mean = numpy.matrix([[0],[0]])
cov = numpy.matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
```

When I receive in inupt a column vector of **integers** values (x,y) I want to compute the probability of that given tuple.

```
value = numpy.matrix([[4],[3]])
probability_of_value_given_the_distribution = ???
```

Now, from a matematical point of view, this would be the integral for `3.5 < x < 4.5` and `2.5 < y < 3.5` over the probability density function of my normal.

**What I want to know:**

Is there a way to avoid the effective implementation of this, that implies dealing with expressions defined over matrices and with double integrals? Besides that it will take me a while if I had to implement it by myself, this would be computationally expensive. An approximate solution would be perfectly fine for me.

**My reasonings:**

In an univariate normal, one could simply use the cumulative distribution function (or even store its values for the standard one and then normalize), but unfortunately there appears [not to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) a closed cdf form for multivariates.

Another approach for univariate is to use the inverse of [bivariate approximation](http://www.mathsrevision.net/alevel/pages.php?page=63) (so, approximate a normal as a binomial), but extending this to the multivariate I can't figure out how to keep in count the covariances.

I really hope someone has already implemented this, I need it soon (finishing my thesis) and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have you checked [Compute the multivariate normal CDF in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178759/compute-the-multivariate-normal-cdf-in-java), it seems to be exactly what your trying to do

Comment: The cdf is exactly what I need. I'm sorry for not having it specified explicitly. Apparently is not that trivial, I will either make some approximation or use matlab to compute the values that are of interest in my program and store them in a table (program runs on android, so no way to execute fortran code there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenTURNS provides an efficient implementation of the CDF of a multinormal distribution (see the [code](https://github.com/openturns/openturns/blob/b746a3e8e41445d4110b324c08b4ddb3211312b7/lib/src/Uncertainty/Distribution/Normal.cxx#L236)).

```
import numpy as np

mean = np.array([0.0, 0.0])
cov = np.array([[1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 1.0]])
```

Let us create the multinormal distribution with these parameters.

```
import openturns as ot
multinormal = ot.Normal(mean, ot.CovarianceMatrix(cov))
```

Now let us compute the probability of the square [3.5, 4.5] x |2.5, 3.5]:

```
prob = multinormal.computeProbability(ot.Interval([3.5,2.5], [4.5,3.5])) 
print(prob)
```

The computed probability is

```
1.3701244220201715e-06
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the [probabiliy density function of a bivariate normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), below are a few lines that could do the job:

```
import numpy as np

def multivariate_pdf(vector, mean, cov):
    quadratic_form = np.dot(np.dot(vector-mean,np.linalg.inv(cov)),np.transpose(vector-mean))
    return np.exp(-.5 * quadratic_form)/ (2*np.pi * np.linalg.det(cov))

mean = np.array([0,0])
cov = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
vector = np.array([4,3])

pdf = multivariate_pdf(vector, mean, cov)
```

Comment: sorry, but I need the cumulative density function