# Computing integrals of correlated Gaussain random variables

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

Let (X,Y) be a 2-dimensional normal random variable with the 0 mean and the covariance matrix S. Further let Q = [0,1]x[0,1] be a unit square and let us grid it, uniformly each side with N grid points. As a result we obtain that Q is a union of N x N squares. I need to compute the marginal of (X,Y) over each such square in MATLAB, i.e. I need to compute a matrix I which elements are N x N integrals of the form

[image: int1]

where [image: Qij] is the element of the partition. The greedy way is to run two loops: over i and over j, and to compute numerically each of these integrals. However, in case when S is diagonal one can do much more efficient trick: first compute distribution of X (that would be one row vector), then the one of Y (the column vector) and finally take the Kronecker product of them, which will result in the correct matrix I.

However, in case when there is a correlation, i.e. S is not a diagonal matrix, such trick does not work. Is it necessary to run 2 loops in such case, or there is a better way?

Comment: Surprisingly, this website does not support math mode - the only way to use it as far as I understood from meta is via images, which however is very slow and not handy. On the other hand, without using formulas this question may not be clear. Please, tell me if any clarification is needed - e.g. the way how do I do in the case when S is diagonal.

Comment: you have better luck asking in dsp.stackexchange.com.  people here are idiots (see answers below).  they won't know how to answer something like htis.  also, dsp has cool latex math symbols.  what you're doing is simple numerical integration.  when S is not diagonal, you cannot use the same trick because the PDF is not separable.  however, you know that the Gaussian is tilted with different principal axes, and it is separable along these axes.  what you can do is transform the random variables X, Y into A = aX+bY, and B = cX+dY. [a b; c d] is the PCA transformation. This will also tilt your Q.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no simple way to calculate the CDF of a multi-variate Normal distribution in general - see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

If you have the MATLAB Statistics Toolbox, you can use mvncdf:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvncdf.html

There are C/C++ versions available you might be able to MEX:

[multivariate normal cdf in C, C++, or Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109465/multivariate-normal-cdf-in-c-c-or-fortran)

Or, if you want to do everything in MATLAB, try integral2, which has a lot of optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The multivariate normal CDF is not easy to compute. However, the bivariate case is somewhat easier and more accurate than the univariate case, using what you mentioned above. There's both FORTRAN (see below) and pure Java libraries for it: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/indexe.html

More generally, WSU Professor (Alan Genz) has been researching how to do this and other multivariate integrals numerically since the 1980's. All of the code that others have implemented are derived from his algorithm and research. His code can compute the CDF and expectation of the multivariate normal and T distributions for dimensions up to 1000.

http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/software/software.html

I've also written code to call those subroutines from Java: [Compute the multivariate normal CDF in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178759/compute-the-multivariate-normal-cdf-in-java)