# Statistic Library for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, statistics, correlation

I know that there are plenty of packages for java for statistic calculation but in this case i need one for objective C.
I scope of an App i need to calculate  Cramer's V
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V of nominal attributes of some classes based on their attributes.I do not want to reinvent the wheel.I also need to find linear correlation and other basic operations as well.

Are there any known open source good libraries for such purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out C/C++ libraries: [wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C), [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746364/best-library-for-statistics-in-c).