# What statistical distribution is used to benchmark an algorithm?

Tags: statistics, benchmarking, static-analysis

I have benchmarked my algorithm, it run for 1000 times. Now I have all time values and at this point it would be interesting to know the mean, standard deviation, median. The problem is that I don't know what is correct statistics to use to estimate these parameters. I'm not sure about using Normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics). There are lots of books, guides, papers and introductions out there ([1](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/LaTeX/Examples/statistics_firstfive.pdf),[2](http://www.sagepub.com/upm-data/40006_Chapter1.pdf),[3](http://www.amazon.de/Statistics-An-Introduction-using-R/dp/0470022981), [4](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2005/))
There are also lots of libraries which implements default statistical methods:

- [Java Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html),
- [C++ Libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746364/best-library-for-statistics-in-c),
- and there are certainly lots of others for the language you use...

And also one last hint: For a quick (initial) result I often use [excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/) and its diagram functions. It supports some statistical methods with which you can play around a bit to see in which direction you may continue....

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what distribution your workload experiences, so you would not be able to answer generically to this.

But there is a trick: if you go one step forward, and do several iterations, each consisting of N calls, and compute, say, average time/throughput for the entire iteration. Then, for a large N and consistent workload behavior across the calls, the iteration scores may be subject to [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), which can turn them into normally distributed.