# How to find statistical distribution using C++?

Tags: c++, statistics, distribution, analysis

Is there relevant functions/ libraries that can be used to analyse data in C++? For example, finding the distribution of a given set of data, such as Weibull/Exponential/Gamma/Normal distribution with accurate parameters?

If not, what other languages are good at data analysis other than Matlab and R?

Comment: as usually with c++, there is no built-in (read: standard library) function to do this, but there are dozens of libraries you can use. See e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746364/best-library-for-statistics-in-c

Comment: Take a look at Scipy for Python.